# Order of transition group in Semnatic UI components

Tags: jquery, transition, semantic-ui, fade, semantic-ui-css

I am using Semantic UI transition (css,js), and there are some html objects to fade in:

```html
<div id="div1" class="fadding1 transition">
<div id="div2" class="fadding1 transition">
<div id="div3" class="fadding1 transition">
<div id="div4" class="fadding1 transition">
<div id="div5" class="fadding1 transition">
```

Then I can fade them in sequential order by calling from jQuery script:

```html
$('.fadding1').transition({
            animation: 'fade',
            duration: 1500,
            interval: 400
        });
```

So, they start fading in from *div1* to *div5* in order, one after each other.
Now, lets say I want them to fade in this order *div1*, *div4*, *div5*, *div2* and *div3*.
I tried **onComplete**, with two different classes like below, **but** it is triggered after **each** individual component fades.

```html
<div id="div1" class="fadding1 transition">
<div id="div2" class="fadding2 transition">
<div id="div3" class="fadding2 transition">
<div id="div4" class="fadding1 transition">
<div id="div5" class="fadding1 transition">
```

and jQuery script:

```html
$('.fadding1').transition({
            animation: 'fade',
            duration: 1500,
            interval: 400,
            onComplete: function() {
                $('.fadding2').transition({
                    animation: 'fade',
                    duration: 1500,
                    interval: 400
                });
        });
```

So making different classes (1,4,5) and (2,3) is not helping. The last solution is making a cascading functional tree, which is not desirable since I have plenty of components (not only five).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the best workaround. Use the id of the last item in the first fading group. in the **onComplete** function, check if it refers to that id, then second fading group starts.

```html
<div id="div1" class="fadding1 transition">
<div id="div2" class="fadding2 transition">
<div id="div3" class="fadding2 transition">
<div id="div4" class="fadding1 transition">
<div id="div5" class="fadding1 transition">
```

Checking the id, and starting the second fading action:

```html
$('.fadding1').transition({
            animation: 'fade',
            duration: 1500,
            interval: 400,
            onComplete: function() {
                if(this.id=="div5"){
                    $('.fadding2').transition({
                        animation: 'fade',
                        duration: 1500,
                        interval: 400
                    });
                }
        });
```